# Google Analytics not registering some variables

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

In the `document.ready()` function of my application's main layout GSP, I have the following code:

```
var pageTitle = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;
if('index' == 'list') {
    pageTitle += " Listing";
}
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)}ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto', 'AppTracker', {
    userId: 'uniqueUser',
    campaignId: '123',
    campaignSource: 'app',
    campaignName: '123',
    title: pageTitle
});
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

What I'm trying to do is use Google Analytics to track access to the application.  Unfortunately, right now neither page titles nor campaignId / names seem to be showing up in our GA account.  Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Campaign parameters and page title cannot be defined in the `create` method. Here's what I see when I run your code:

[image]

So, as per the warning message, use the `set` method instead.

cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#create

Comment: Derpty derp.  Thanks.  I will try that and report back.

Comment: Curious ... you said "here's what I see when I run your code" ... in what environment are you running that code?

Comment: I just copy and pasted it into a dev console on my own site, and I also have GA Debugger tool enabled, so I can see all the debug messages pertinent to GA (that's where my screenshot is from). Great tool to have, by the way!

Comment: I am developing in FF and didn't see anything in the JS console and so I was wondering.  I will investigate how to get GA Debugger enabled in FF.

Answer (score 0):

This code ended up working.  I was able to arrive at this code by taking nyuen's advice and installing a GA debugger.  Unfortunately, the FF add-on does not display anything unless the request is successful, so it was necessary to install the add-on for Chrome.  The Chrome debugger for GA is phenomenal and gives you all the error messages you could hope for.

```
var pageTitle = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;
if('${actionName}' == 'list') {
    pageTitle += " Listing";
}
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)} ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1');
ga('set', 'userId', 'uniqueUser');
ga('set', 'campaignId', '123');
ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'app');
ga('set', 'campaignName', '123');
ga('set', 'title', pageTitle);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```